# Set value of a select input to the value of last request in Django form template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Here is my template code

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="{{ form.diagnosis.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">{{ form.diagnosis.label }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm{% if form.diagnosis.errors %} is-invalid{% endif %}" id="{{ form.diagnosis.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.diagnosis.html_name }}" value="{{ form.diagnosis.value }}" required>
        {% if form.diagnosis.errors %}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {% for error in form.diagnosis.errors %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% elif form.diagnosis.help_text %}
        <small class="form-text text-muted">
            {{ form.diagnosis.help_text }}
        </small>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="{{ form.assigned_employee.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">{{ form.assigned_employee.label }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm{% if form.assigned_employee.errors %} is-invalid{% endif %}" id="{{ form.assigned_employee.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.assigned_employee.html_name }}">
            {% for id, name in form.fields.assigned_employee.choices %}
                <option value="{{ id }}"{% if form.assigned_employee.value == id %} selected{% endif %}>{{ name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        {% if form.assigned_employee.errors %}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {% for error in form.assigned_employee.errors %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% elif form.assigned_employee.help_text %}
        <small class="form-text text-muted">
            {{ form.assigned_employee.help_text }}
        </small>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have created the form template manually and would like to keep it that way.

I can set the values of previously submitted fields using `{{ form.field.value }}`. But I can't do the same for the `<select>` fields.

I have tried to do so using the following

```
{% for id, name in form.fields.assigned_employee.choices %}
    <option value="{{ id }}"{% if form.assigned_employee.value == id %} selected{% endif %}>{{ name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

. But it doesn't work except for when I set an initial value for the field like `form = SomeForm(initial={'assigned_employee': 20180011})`

The interesting thing is `form.assigned_employee.value` returns a value after submission. I have checked it using `console.log({{ form.assigned_employee.value }})`.

But the evaluation of the following condition `{% if form.assigned_employee.value == id %} selected{% endif %}` is always `false`.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on?

Comment: The value is probably a string (because it needs to be displayed as text) whereas the id is an int.

Comment: Thought of it. But how do I make such a comparison in the template? @DanielRoseman

Comment: @ShateelAhmed Check the edit to see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the evaluation of the following condition {% if form.assigned_employee.value == id %} selected{% endif %} is always false.

That's because you forget to put **fields**; You should use `{% if form.fields.assigned_employee.value == id %}` not `{% if form.assigned_employee.value == id %}`:

```
{% for id, name in form.fields.assigned_employee.choices %}
    <option value="{{ id }}"{% if form.fields.assigned_employee.value == id %} selected{% endif %}>{{ name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

#### Edit

As mentioned in the comments by [@Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman), if you want to convert int to string in the template, you can use:

```
{% for id, name in form.fields.assigned_employee.choices %}
    <option value="{{ id }}"{% if form.assigned_employee.value == id|stringformat:"i" %} selected{% endif %}>{{ name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have tried that. Doesn't work. Besides I have mentioned that `form.assigned_employee.value` does return a value